# Working with C# desktop app, C# MAUI app and SQL Server together

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvvm, maui

I want to design an application both for desktop and Android mobile.
My present application is targeting only desktop with a local SQL Server database.

I want to share the same SQL Server database with MAUI Android app & in the future I'm planning to keep the database on a cloud server too.
I want to know exact approach for this scenario.

Should I have single solution with two projects - one for the desktop and another for MAUI?

What about data access? Could I share data access classes with both desktop and Android app, or do I have to implement them separately in both projects?

What should the folder structure be like?

Right now I created a new solution in Visual Studio and added one class library project to handle activities related to the database (connection open/close, DML statements handling etc).

Another project is for the desktop app in the same solution which will access that class library project for data related services.

Up to here, it's working fine.

Now what about MAUI application that I want to add to this solution? How should I implement MVVM ? How do I avoid duplication of code?

Another point here is, I need to design two separate UI for desktop and mobile because I am using DevExpress controls in my MAUI app for android which do not support desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support a desktop and you are at the beginning of your project, you could use another UI Library, such as Syncfusion which offers support for desktop apps.

About your project, you can control the page navigation to desktop equivalent pages, you can choose the approach of keeping two UI folders or two projects separated if you want to keep the UI different. I prefer to keep the UI in a single project and separate just folders and control them by a navigation class, you could start your folder organization below using [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm) and using the library [community for MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/).

```
|-project
|--ViewModels
|--Views
|----Desktop
|----Mobile
```

However, MAUI supports you keep a single XAML for a handle with both UI, using [OnPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/customize-ui-appearance?view=net-maui-8.0)

```
|-project
|--ViewModels
|--Views
```

About the database, you can use a WebAPI for integrating both apps for mobile and desktop apps. Keep in mind if you connect your app android directly to Database it could cause a security issue if you don't have full control of the network that the apps will be using. That's why I recommend an API for that.

Comment: Thanks Marcos for early reply.
I also want to know more about what you mean about WebAPI and Connecting Directly to Database?

Comment: I have non knowledge abount web development.
My primary Interest is about Desktop and Mobile only.


I am using Local Databases on machine for MS Desktop application so far, and my initial requirement is also limited upto Local Area Network only.


say for mobile app also I want to use Local DB on Desktop Machine within Wi-Fi LAN network, however I haven't yet discovered how would I connect mobile app with DB, is it possible to consume the same data services of desktop app with mobile app too eliminating the WebAPI (I dont know about yet)?

Comment: Exposing a database to public (even within your local network) is a security risk and you can limit that risk that with a WebApi. There are thousands of articels in the WWW dealing with WebApi

Comment: Would it be possible to deploy the app on respective devices separately if I keep Desktop and Mobile app UI in same project with just separate Folders?

Comment: You must deploy them separately, they are two separate packages, one for Android (.aab/.apk) and one for Windows (.exe).